# How can I see the native code which is created ART of Android?

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Now, I have a bug of my application on the device running Android 6.0. I suspect that the double-checked locking pattern using the keyword "volatile" on Marshmallow ART does not work correctly.

Thus, I want to check the native code which is created ART of Android. How can I do that?